# Почему в этом сложном предложении нет запятой?

Tags: синтаксис

"Дверь в купе приоткрылась и внутрь заглянул один из рыжих мальчиков" –– предложение, прочтенное в книге "Гарри Поттер и Философский Камень". Мне интересно, почему тут нет запятой.

Две грамматические основы: дверь открылась и один из рыжих мальчиков заглянул.

Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить? Такое чувство, что тут ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь, действительно, ошибка, так как запятая нужна

Comment: Запятая нужна, это ССП. Скорее всего, здесь ошибка корректора. Если найти это предложение в поисковике, то встречаются разные записи - с запятой и без запятой.

Comment: Но я-то это предложение в книге увидел ;)

Comment: Какой я молодец! Ошибку нашел!